# How to translate animate a div from outside to its final position?

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate, css-animations, velocity.js

I'd like to do an animation using either CSS, jQuery or Velocity.js to slide in from any side of the browser window to it's final position.

All the divs I want animated are placed using Bootstrap and I'd like for the animation to start the divs from outside from a particular side of the browser and it'll slide into the position that it's currently in without animations.

Basically, the divs and the entire site is built where everything is supposed to be at the moment and I want to include animations to slide the objects onto the body of the page.

I don't know any jQuery or Velocity animations so feel free to submit code or fiddles. I searched many different things but I couldn't find an answer. I only see solutions to slide them out of the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

See if this is what you need. The key is the `animation`.

```css
.container {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: #def;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow: hidden;
  animation: slide-from-right 2s;
}

@keyframes slide-from-right {
  from {
    left: 100vw;
  }
  to {
    left: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
  <form>
    <input placeholder="Some input">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It works great! But it creates scroll bars for the period that it's outside.

Comment: @KCB4Rockstar how about now?

Comment: I tried the overflow but the scroll bars still appeared. I didn't mention that it was the scroll bars for the entire window, not the div itself.
I did a fix by doing `overflow-x: hidden;` on the `body` but that's probably not the best solution.

Comment: Probably adding `margin: 0` to `.container`?

Comment: Didn't work. Once something is sliding in from the right side of the screen. It creates the horizontal scroll bar for the window